# Установка и запуск Tomcat 8 на Ubuntu 16.04 Проблема

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

Надо поставить томкат на убунту.

Нашел этот гайд: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-n-ubuntu-16-04

Скачал томкат отсюда https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi.

Всу ок до момента запуска томката. Когда пытаюсь запустить появляется ошибка:

```
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Команда `systemctl status tomcat.service` показывает это:

```
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-03-22 15:26:39 CET; 4min 40s ago
Process: 1578 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container...
Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container.
Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

что не так?

Comment: а можно вопрос не по теме, а зачем Вам томкат?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ что бы запустить Java приложение

Comment: это я к тому, что есть способы по проще чем томкат, чтобы запустить java приложение...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ какие? надо запустить не бут приложение.

Comment: последнее я не понял, какое приложение?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ приложение не на Spring Boot

Comment: погуглите undertow, jetty